# My jQuery is not working with IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, console

So I got three pieces of code to load stuff into div and do other things. But it doesn't work with Internet Explorer, I checked IE11 console and that's what I got

```
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined
```

That's odd, in every other browser it works fine, I tried to google it but didn't find any solution to this.

Here's my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#description').load('descr/portDefault.htm');
    $('#portNav').load('menus/default.htm');
```

@edit

I guess I forgot to put the entire code, here it is: http://pastebin.com/xCL1e7Fh
This html is an iframe in another html file if that makes a difference.

Comment: Where do you load the actual jQuery library?

Comment: So, obviously your IE11 is having trouble loading jQuery.  You will have to give us some more clues as to what is going on before we'd have any idea why.  Are you loading anything `async` or `defer`?  Please include in your question the exact code that loads jQuery before you use it.  Do you have any code that is doing `$.noConflict()`.  Are you using an jQuery plugins?  Are there any other errors shown in the error console?

Comment: here's the entire code http://pastebin.com/xCL1e7Fh

Comment: no other errors, just this one 3 times

Comment: Does "jQuery" work? jQuery(document)

Comment: what exactly do you mean Daved? There's one more error I ommited, sorry - SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'attachEvent'

Comment: $ is just a shorthand reference to jQuery, the actual object. Instead of $('.myselector').click() you can do "jQuery('.myselector').click()". Does using "longhand" to call "jQuery" instead of "$" work? You can test in the console to reproduce errors.

Comment: Still doesn't work, now I only get this error "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'attachEvent'".

Comment: What is strange, if I open this html file directly in IE it works fine, but when I open main page where this file is an iframe it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see an iframe in your code example. Is the jquery file being loaded in an iframe? And where is the script executing?

Comment: Here's the code of the main page: http://pastebin.com/m9x9kKXJ jQuery is being loaded both in main page and iframe. The first example code is an iframe itself.

Comment: Fixed, IE is stupid as hell. All I had to do was to put the SAME src for jquery in main page and in iframe. My iframe page was in another folder so src paths were different which caused the problem, all I had to do is either move my iframes to the same folder as main page and change the src path to be the same, or change src path in iframe to the same as main page but copy jquery.js to the folder where my iframes are stored. That's confusing I know.

Comment: TL;DR - your path to jquery in main page and iframe must exactly THE SAME, it doesn't matter if it leads to same file but the path is different (src="jquery.js" in main page and src="../jquery.js in iframe)

DUH!

Comment: @user2660811 Notice, that `'attachEvent` is [obsoleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986080%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE11.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I thought I had the fix with the compatability set in the meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1" />
```

It worked, but that triggered me to check compatablity settting in IE11.
For a previous project I had added localhost to the list in the Compatability View Settings.

Cleared the list and it works well now (without the meta tag).