# Jquery in IE not loaded

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, php, x-cart

I want to ask about jquery. in my website http://dev-4-6-1.zgrum.com/ when open in IE the jquery cant load. What a problem in this? and The slider can't show.
But when open using chrome, firefox, its everything ok.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

thank you

Comment: Here are some old "fixes" for the problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110078/my-jquery-is-not-working-with-ie11 - http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/698340/which-version-of-jquery-we-can-use-for-IE

Comment: I have add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1" /> still same.