# jQuery.html() insert input field won't work in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem regarding jQuery's .html method. I am using the following event to insert a input field in a table row when double clicking on it. Everything works fine in Google Chrome and Firefox - but it won't work in Internet Explorer 11.

The code is the following:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '.myTable tbody tr td:not(:first-child)', function () {
  var originContent = this.innerText;
  $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + originContent + '">')
  $(this).children().focus();
});
```

I also tried it with the following way to insert the input field:

```
$(this).html($('<input />', {
 type: "text",
 value: originContent
}));
```

But it won't work. There is no error in the IE11 console - it just don't replaces the innerHTML. But notice: if I try to replace the inner html in the debug session with a number or string like .html(1234) or .html('string') it works.

What am I doing wrong? Anyone else noticed a problem like that?

Comment: Can you give more details than 'it doesn't work'. What happens? What doesn't happen? Any errors in the console? Have you made any effort to debug this at all - if so, what?

Comment: Why are you using html() and not append() ?

Comment: Sorry for the missing information - I also included it to the original post. Well, no error appears in console. It just not replace the html content of the table row. As I tested it it works if I replace it with just a string or so like .html(1234) or .html('string')

Comment: @epascarello I'd imagine it's some sort of span or paragraph that, when double-clicked, becomes an editable input. Not that this rules out `append()` by any means, but that would require the deletion of the previous content as well - `html()` can of course just do it in one swoop. Perhaps there's a reason to use `.append()` here that I haven't considered?

Comment: Indeed @TylerRoper the row includes a text string with the original content which can be edited after double clicked.

Comment: So empty() and append()

Comment: Well it seems like that the concatenating is the problem...manually appending while debugging is working like $(this).empty().append('<input type="text" value="test">');

Comment: Seems to work just fine in IE: http://jsbin.com/fuseluguvi/1/edit Please provide a [Minimal Verifiable Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually demonstrates the issue. Otherwise, all the rest of us can do is wildly guess what the problem is.

Comment: @erfurtjohn Does the value contain any quotation characters or angle brackets perhaps? This is why you shouldn't be using string concatenation to build HTML.

Comment: @JLRishe it just contains a float number like 3,1234 or 3.213

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is loading for you in IE11? I just tried to create an MCVE for this and it didn't work, telling me that `$` was not defined. After adding the meta tag described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23295086/), your code dropped in the text field as desired. I'll write up the sample code as an answer if that turns out to be your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My jQuery is not working with IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110078/my-jquery-is-not-working-with-ie11)

Comment: jQuery is working at all, but not my html appending with value. I tried again and appending just the element without a value like <input type="text" value=""> is working! But if I try to set value after appending with .val() it doesnt work again....very weird!

Comment: I also noticed, that jQuery indeed appends it because I can see the element listed in $(this).children() after appending with the value! But it doesn't appear on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why und how but apparently the *$(this).children().focus();* crashed it or prevent showing it up in IE....

Edit: the error was procudes due an wrong event I handled. My first event reacted on double click on table row - after appending the html input field I changed the focus to the input element.

But my second event handler should've react on focus out of the input element but I missed a input in the selector. So everytime I clicked on the table row I inserted the input and removed it coincident. Why it works then in Chrome is still weird, guess it just knows what I want ¯_(ツ)_/¯